# Is there a workaround to set a relative RPATH in CMake under Windows

Tags: cmake, cross-compiling, rpath

I want to set the RPATH in CMake to `$ORIGIN`. I am cross-compiling for a Linux system on my Windows machine. I need to set the RPATH property to `$ORIGIN`. For that I use the following code.

```
set_target_properties(LibraryName PROPERTIES INSTALL_RPATH "\$ORIGIN")
```

What I get is `\$ORIGIN`.

I also tried different ways to escape the $ sign

```
set_target_properties(LibraryName PROPERTIES INSTALL_RPATH "$ORIGIN") -> \$ORIGIN
set_target_properties(LibraryName PROPERTIES INSTALL_RPATH $ORIGIN) -> \$ORIGIN
set_target_properties(LibraryName PROPERTIES INSTALL_RPATH \$ORIGIN) -> \$ORIGIN
set_target_properties(LibraryName PROPERTIES INSTALL_RPATH "\\\$ORIGIN") -> \\\$ORIGIN
```

When I cross-compile the same project using a Linux machine, than it works. Meaning `"\$ORIGIN"` -> `$ORIGIN`.
I already opened a [defect](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/21291) in the CMake Issue Tracker, but that takes some time I guess. Is there a workaround how I can set the RPATH in Windows? Maybe some command line tool or other hack? ;-)

**EDIT**

I tried even more things:

```
set_target_properties(LibraryName PROPERTIES INSTALL_RPATH [=[$ORIGIN]=]) => \$ORIGIN

set(ORIGIN_RPATH [=[$ORIGIN]=])
set_target_properties(FancyLibrary PROPERTIES INSTALL_RPATH ${ORIGIN_RPATH})  => \$ORIGIN

cmake_policy(SET CMP0095 OLD) + any of the mentioned variations => \$ORIGIN
```

When I look into the build.make file I find the escaped linker option `-Wl,-rpath,"\$$ORIGIN"`
Is there a way to at least manipulate the generated build.make before it is executed?

Comment: Could this be related to the issue described in [CMP0095](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.18/policy/CMP0095.html#policy:CMP0095)?

Comment: That sounded good, but unfortunately did not solve the problem. I set the policy to OLD and even used an older version of CMAKE (3.14.7), but I still got the escaped \$ORIGIN